# Laravel foreach array in view

Tags: arrays, laravel, foreach

In database I have Cities table with Features column, and one City (row) can contain multiple features in the Feature cell like this ["1", "2", "3"]. I also have Features table with matching features with id and title.

In specific City page I'm trying to foreach the features that belong to that one city, like this:

```
@foreach ($city->features as $feature => $chosenfeature)
    @foreach ($features as $feature)
         @if ($feature->id == $chosenfeature)
               {{ $feature->title }}
         @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

But I get an error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where does `$featureS` come from? You labelled the key `$feature` and then directly underneath in the second loop, you add an S to it?

Comment: you are receiving either null or string value in `$city->features`. You have to json_decode the $city->features to use it in foreach loop

Comment: $features come from Features table which are seperate from Cities. Features contain id and title for each feature. I can foreach all the Features and all the Cities no problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try as below. you've taken key as `$feature`
`@foreach ($city->features as $feature => $chosenfeature)`

and  `@foreach ($features as $feature)` here alias is the same as `$feature`.

```
@foreach (json_decode($city->features) as $chosenfeature)
    @foreach ($features as $feature)
         @if ($feature->id == $chosenfeature)
               {{ $feature->title }}
         @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score -1):

It just means `$city->features` isnt an iterable. Print out `$city->features` somewhere to see what the variable contains

Comment: {{$city->features}} returns ["1", "2"]

Comment: @JatZ this is string use json_decode to make it as object or array so it is iterable

Comment: Okay, how do I do that?

Comment: @foreach (json_decode($fleamarket->features) as $chosenfeature)
Got it work using this! Thanks guys!

Comment: @JatZ you might need to check if the value is not null before foreach too if you are allowing the null value in database